# Extension methods on Enum - unable to expose methods on the Enum itself

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods

Consider this Enum:

```
enum State
{
    On,
    Off
}
```

... And this extension method:

```
public static void Foo(this Enum e)
{
    // Here be dragons...
}
```

If I want to call *Foo()*, I have to call it on one of the Enum's properties: `State.On.Foo()`... I can't call it on the Enum itself: `State.Foo()`.

Why is this? And what do I need to do, to be able to call *Foo()* on the Enum itself?

Answer (score 7):

If you try to call `State.Foo()`, that's trying to call a *static* method on `Foo`. Extension methods extend *instances* of a type. They're like adding instance methods to that type, but without being able to add any state.

To give an example of why this wouldn't work, what would you expect this code to do?

```
int count = IEnumerable<string>.Count();
```

You can't fake adding *static* methods to a type. It's just not something that extension methods support.

Comment: Would I be able to add Foo() along the side of Enum.Format(), Enum.GetName() etc.?

Comment: @roosteronacid: No, those are static methods. You can't fake adding static methods to a type.

Comment: @roosterronacid Hi, don't think you can. As Jon stated, extension methods are used for instances of objects. For some examples on how to work around this you can have a look at e.g. http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=255 I'm not so sure that doing this will actually give you code that looks so much better or is easier to maintain, but you can have a look at the code examples anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is because extension methods can only be called on **instance**, not **class**. They are just a syntactic sugar for static methods.